pgAdmin 4 v8 Fatal Error (The pgAdmin 4 server could not be contacted:)
I just upgraded pgAdmin 4 to version 8 with PosgreSQL 16. But when I opened pgAdmin I got a notification like this. Anyone know what I should do?

pgAdmin Runtime Environment
Python Path: "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\python\python.exe"
Runtime Config File: "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Roaming\pgadmin\runtime_config.json"
pgAdmin Config File: "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\web\config.py"
Webapp Path: "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\web\pgAdmin4.py"
pgAdmin Command: "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\python\python.exe -s C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\web\pgAdmin4.py"
Environment:
ALLUSERSPROFILE: C:\ProgramData
APPDATA: C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Roaming
asl.log: Destination=file
ChocolateyInstall: C:\ProgramData\chocolatey
ChocolateyLastPathUpdate: 133210276127704990
CHROME_CRASHPAD_PIPE_NAME: \.\pipe\crashpad_17132_BFJSELQKUUUBFMFD
CHROME_RESTART: NW.js|Whoa! NW.js has crashed. Relaunch now?|LEFT_TO_RIGHT
CommonProgramFiles: C:\Program Files\Common Files
CommonProgramFiles(x86): C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
CommonProgramW6432: C:\Program Files\Common Files
COMPUTERNAME: DESKTOP-1OD3TO3
ComSpec: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
CURL_CA_BUNDLE: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\ssl\certs\ca-bundle.crt
DriverData: C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
EFC_10096: 1
GDAL_DATA: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\gdal-data
GOPATH: C:\Users\SOS\go
HOMEDRIVE: C:
HOMEPATH: \Users\SOS
LOCALAPPDATA: C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local
LOGONSERVER: \DESKTOP-1OD3TO3
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS: 8
OneDrive: C:\Users\SOS\OneDrive
OneDriveConsumer: C:\Users\SOS\OneDrive
OPENSSL_CONF: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\psqlODBC\etc\openssl.cnf
OS: Windows_NT
Path: C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\runtime;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\PuTTY;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\xampp\php;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Program Files\FME;C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin;C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem;C:\Users\SOS\Dropbox\My PC (DESKTOP-1OD3TO3)\Downloads\Programs\mongosh-1.0.0-win32-x64\mongosh-1.0.0-win32-x64\bin;C:\Program Files\Go\bin;C:\Program Files\dotnet;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\WolframScript;C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts;C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311;C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\TestProject Agent;C:\Users\SOS\go\bin;
PATHEXT: .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
PGADMIN_INT_KEY: a898d4a8-cded-4559-8eb6-7505e5956741
PGADMIN_INT_PORT: 53208
PGADMIN_SERVER_MODE: OFF
POSTGIS_ENABLE_OUTDB_RASTERS: 1
POSTGIS_GDAL_ENABLED_DRIVERS: GTiff PNG JPEG GIF XYZ DTED USGSDEM AAIGrid
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE: AMD64
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER: Intel64 Family 6 Model 126 Stepping 5, GenuineIntel
PROCESSOR_LEVEL: 6
PROCESSOR_REVISION: 7e05
ProgramData: C:\ProgramData
ProgramFiles: C:\Program Files
ProgramFiles(x86): C:\Program Files (x86)
ProgramW6432: C:\Program Files
PROJ_LIB: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\share\contrib\postgis-3.4\proj
PSModulePath: C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
PUBLIC: C:\Users\Public
SESSIONNAME: Console
SystemDrive: C:
SystemRoot: C:\WINDOWS
TEMP: C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Temp
TMP: C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Temp
USERDOMAIN: DESKTOP-1OD3TO3
USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE: DESKTOP-1OD3TO3
USERNAME: SOS
USERPROFILE: C:\Users\SOS
windir: C:\WINDOWS
ZES_ENABLE_SYSMAN: 1
Total spawn time to start the pgAdmin4 server: 0.013 Sec
2024-05-27 14:08:28,744: ERROR    pgadmin:    Database migration failed
2024-05-27 14:08:28,759: ERROR    pgadmin:    Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1971, in _exec_single_context
self.dialect.do_execute(
File "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 919, in do_execute
cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlite3.OperationalError: duplicate column name: shared
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\web\pgadmin_init_.py", line 386, in upgrade_db
db_upgrade(app)
File "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\web\pgadmin\setup\db_upgrade.py", line 25, in db_upgrade
flask_migrate.upgrade(migration_folder)
File "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\flask_migrate_init_.py", line 111, in wrapped
f(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\flask_migrate_init_.py", line 200, in upgrade
command.upgrade(config, revision, sql=sql, tag=tag)
File "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\alembic\command.py", line 403, in upgrade
script.run_env()
File "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\alembic\script\base.py", line 583, in run_env
util.load_python_file(self.dir, "env.py")
File "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\alembic\util\pyfiles.py", line 95, in load_python_file
module = load_module_py(module_id, path)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\alembic\util\pyfiles.py", line 113, in load_module_py
spec.loader.exec_module(module)  # type: ignore
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 995, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in call_with_frames_removed
File "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\web\pgadmin\setup....\migrations\env.py", line 95, in <module>
run_migrations_online()
File "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\web\pgadmin\setup....\migrations\env.py", line 87, in run_migrations_online
context.run_migrations()
File "<string>", line 8, in run_migrations
File "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\alembic\runtime\environment.py", line 948, in run_migrations
self.get_context().run_migrations(**kw)
File "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\alembic\runtime\migration.py", line 627, in run_migrations
step.migration_fn(**kw)
File "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\web\migrations\versions\a091c9611d20.py", line 27, in upgrade
op.add_column('server', sa.Column('shared', sa.Boolean()))
File "<string>", line 8, in add_column
File "<string>", line 3, in add_column
File "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\alembic\operations\ops.py", line 2142, in add_column
return operations.invoke(op)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\alembic\operations\base.py", line 445, in invoke
return fn(self, operation)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\alembic\operations\toimpl.py", line 171, in add_column
operations.impl.add_column(table_name, column, schema=schema, **kw)
File "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\alembic\ddl\impl.py", line 334, in add_column
self._exec(base.AddColumn(table_name, column, schema=schema))
File "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\alembic\ddl\impl.py", line 207, in _exec
return conn.execute(construct, multiparams)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1422, in execute
return meth(
^^^^^
File "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\ddl.py", line 180, in _execute_on_connection
return connection._execute_ddl(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1533, in _execute_ddl
ret = self._execute_context(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1850, in _execute_context
return self._exec_single_context(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1990, in _exec_single_context
self._handle_dbapi_exception(
File "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2357, in _handle_dbapi_exception
raise sqlalchemy_exception.with_traceback(exc_info[2]) from e
File "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1971, in _exec_single_context
self.dialect.do_execute(
File "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 919, in do_execute
cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) duplicate column name: shared
[SQL: ALTER TABLE server ADD COLUMN shared BOOLEAN]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1971, in _exec_single_context
self.dialect.do_execute(
File "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 919, in do_execute
cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlite3.OperationalError: duplicate column name: shared
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\web\pgadmin_init_.py", line 386, in upgrade_db
db_upgrade(app)
File "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\web\pgadmin\setup\db_upgrade.py", line 25, in db_upgrade
flask_migrate.upgrade(migration_folder)
File "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\flask_migrate_init_.py", line 111, in wrapped
f(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\flask_migrate_init_.py", line 200, in upgrade
command.upgrade(config, revision, sql=sql, tag=tag)
File "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\alembic\command.py", line 403, in upgrade
script.run_env()
File "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\alembic\script\base.py", line 583, in run_env
util.load_python_file(self.dir, "env.py")
File "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\alembic\util\pyfiles.py", line 95, in load_python_file
module = load_module_py(module_id, path)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\alembic\util\pyfiles.py", line 113, in load_module_py
spec.loader.exec_module(module)  # type: ignore
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 995, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\web\pgadmin\setup....\migrations\env.py", line 95, in <module>
run_migrations_online()
File "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\web\pgadmin\setup....\migrations\env.py", line 87, in run_migrations_online
context.run_migrations()
File "<string>", line 8, in run_migrations
File "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\alembic\runtime\environment.py", line 948, in run_migrations
self.get_context().run_migrations(**kw)
File "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\alembic\runtime\migration.py", line 627, in run_migrations
step.migration_fn(**kw)
File "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\web\migrations\versions\a091c9611d20_.py", line 27, in upgrade
op.add_column('server', sa.Column('shared', sa.Boolean()))
File "<string>", line 8, in add_column
File "<string>", line 3, in add_column
File "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\alembic\operations\ops.py", line 2142, in add_column
return operations.invoke(op)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\alembic\operations\base.py", line 445, in invoke
return fn(self, operation)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\alembic\operations\toimpl.py", line 171, in add_column
operations.impl.add_column(table_name, column, schema=schema, **kw)
File "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\alembic\ddl\impl.py", line 334, in add_column
self._exec(base.AddColumn(table_name, column, schema=schema))
File "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\alembic\ddl\impl.py", line 207, in _exec
return conn.execute(construct, multiparams)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1422, in execute
return meth(
^^^^^
File "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\ddl.py", line 180, in _execute_on_connection
return connection._execute_ddl(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1533, in _execute_ddl
ret = self._execute_context(
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

File "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1850, in _execute_context
return self._exec_single_context(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1990, in _exec_single_context
self._handle_dbapi_exception(
File "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2357, in _handle_dbapi_exception
raise sqlalchemy_exception.with_traceback(exc_info[2]) from e
File "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1971, in _exec_single_context
self.dialect.do_execute(
File "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 919, in do_execute
cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) duplicate column name: shared
[SQL: ALTER TABLE server ADD COLUMN shared BOOLEAN]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\web\pgAdmin4.py", line 103, in <module>
app = create_app()
^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\web\pgadmin_init_.py", line 473, in create_app
run_migration_for_sqlite()
File "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\web\pgadmin_init_.py", line 432, in run_migration_for_sqlite
upgrade_db()
File "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\web\pgadmin_init_.py", line 391, in upgrade_db
backup_db_file()
File "C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\web\pgadmin_init_.py", line 368, in backup_db_file
os.rename(SQLITE_PATH, backup_file_name)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Roaming\pgAdmin\pgadmin4.db' -> 'C:\Users\SOS\AppData\Roaming\pgAdmin\pgadmin4.db.20240527140828'

I read a similar case, someone suggested deleting the "../Roaming/pgAdmin" folder but it didn't work. I can't delete it, because it is being used in another program on the alert.
